# Set Environment variables for "Load Gradle Changes" of intelliJ

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, groovy, build.gradle

I am working on spring boot project which uses `gradle` script to build and `IntelliJ` as IDE for development. I want to externalize artifactory username/password from my `build.gradle` and `gradle.properties`. One such way is to use environment variables as given here: [Build Environment Properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:project_properties) under heading: `Setting a project property via an environment variable`

I can access variables when I add them to respective task configurations for example `build` task and it run successfully. But I am facing issue when I make changes to build.gradle and `Load Gradle Changes`. Getting errors:

> Exception is:
> org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project.

> Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'password' for root project

My questions:

1. Which gradle task is run when I click on `Load Gradle Changes`.
   So that I can add environment variables in this particular task's
   configuration.
2. How can I add these variables only in one place instead of adding them for each task individually.

Configurations:

- IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1 (Ultimate Edition)
- Gradle 7.2
- Build time:   2021-08-17 09:59:03 UTC
- Revision:    a773786b58bb28710e3dc96c4d1a7063628952ad
- Kotlin:       1.5.21
- Groovy:       3.0.8
- Ant:          Apache Ant(TM)version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
- JVM:          11.0.2(Oracle Corporation 11.0.2+9)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. The environment variable defined in OS is respected when I **Reload** a Gradle project in IDE:

[image]

Make sure you have defined the environment variable properly. Double check it in OS terminal. Also do not forget to restart IDE after you changed the OS environment variables for the IDE to pick up the changes.

Comment: This works for any system variable but doesn't utilize gradle's support for environment properties. Also I want to avoid OS variables as it is not always possible to have access for setting them.